# Error occurs when attempting to Create a Controller in ASP.NET (.net framework) Entity Framework MVC

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, .net-framework-version

I am working with Visual Studio 2022 and ASP.NET (.net framework 4.7.2) and while creating a controller this happen
[image]

I was expecting to create a controller for my project

Comment: Visual studio 2022 doesn't recognized `net framework 4.7.2` please check if you have `net framework 4.7.2` installed in your machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VS 2022 .Net support versions, So Your problem is with the EF package version. Change version of EF to 4.-.- or update .Net version to 6.-.-

```
.NET Framework versions 4.8.1, 4.8, 4.7.2, 4.7.1, 4.7, and 4.6.2
.NET Core 7.0, 6.0, 5.0, 3.1, 3.0, 2.2, and 2.1.
.NET Native
.Mono
```